# Le temps est-il correct ?

Tags: conjugaison, poésie, passé-simple

J'aimerais savoir si le temps employé dans le vers suivant est correct ?

> Débarque la mort, indifférent, tu te tus, démarche alourdie, exaspéré, tu la tues.

Est-ce que le passé simple de "tu te tus" peut être précédé et suivi d'un verbe au présent, à savoir "débarque" et "tu la tues" ?

Comment: Alors, il s'agit de la poésie, et on dirait du rap. Il faut dire qu'il y a une forte tendance vers l'ellipse là-dedans. « Dans une telle situation ... Et quand cela arriva ... » Bien entendu, il faut également constater que le rappeur cherche une rime pour *tues*. On déguise souvent une telle rime basée sur un mot un peu douteux (*tus*) en la mettant en première, comme si on voulait commencer par là et on a trouvé l'autre mot (*tues*), qui semble bien plus naturel grammaticalement, juste par hasard :)

Comment: Bonjour, mon modeste poème est un hommage pour le personnage de Takeshi Kitano dans le film "Hana-bi". Le film joue le contraste entre la naïveté d'un enfant et la fatigue d'un yakuza. Dans ce film, Kitano, le yakuza, est totalement inexpressif, son visage est impassible, même si paradoxalement il exprime des sentiments bien précis. C'est aussi quelqu'un qui est capable telle une foudre d'abattre son ennemi en un clin d'œil d'où mon hyperbole concernant la mort, en effet la mort lui est indifférente. Mais vous ne m'avez pas répondu quant à ma question ?Le temps est-il correct ? La rime marche?

Comment: Oui, si je savais répondre à la question, j'aurais rédigé une réponse plutôt que mon commentaire tentatif :) Ma seule idée, c'est qu'il s'agit d'une ellipse, la matière omise nous permettrant de faire concorder les temps.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que vous appelez la "matière omise" ? Je vous remercie pour les réponses et m'excuse d'avance pour ces questions naïves.

Answer (score 1):

Si on voulait respecter le sens (tel que je le comprends), et une cohérence des temps le plus correct serait :

> Débarque la mort, indifférent, tu te tais, démarche alourdie, tu la tues.

mais on perd la rime. L'autre solution est la suivante :

> Débarqua la mort, indifférent, tu te tus, démarche alourdie, tu la tues.

mais pas parfait non plus (notamment le *tues* de la fin --qui reste au présent--, et le fait que l'enchaînement d'éléments courts séparés par des virgules convient mieux au présent qu'au passé simple)

Answer (score -1):

Moi, je réponds à tout.... // Ici , il y a confusion évidente entre le passé simple du verbe ''taire'' qch ou ''se taire''  et le verbe ''tuer'', donc: tu te taisais = en passé simple = tu te tus et le verbe ''tuer'' qch au mode présent: tu tues qch  >>  toutes les deux conjugaisons ont la même prononciation. //
Conclusion: C'est de la formulation poétique étrangère à la réalité raisonnable des gens communs: Exemple à  fuir > Evitez de lire telle prose destinée à un public littéraire.